# array result using foreach statement display in json in php

Tags: php, json, foreach, soap-client

I am getting the result from web service SOAP client. I have created an array to get the result and display it using json format. I am getting few of my results properly. I have SerialEquipment parameter which is array and i need to get the result using foreach loop. I am doing an mistake there. I dont know how can i assign my $vehiclResult array in this  for each statement. So that all the results at last i will collect and display using json using vehicleResult array.My mistake is in the foreach loop.

structure for SerialEquipment parameters:
[image]

Code:

```
        $vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
             $Serial=$vehicle['SerialEquipment'];
        $vehiclResult = array(
             'WE_Number' => $vehicle['WE Number'] ."<br>", 
             'Vehicle Type'=> $vehicle['Vehicle Type'] . "<br>", 
             'HSN' => $vehicle['HSN'] . "<br>",
             'TSN' => $vehicle['TSN'] . "<br>"
        );
        foreach($Serial as $key => $obj) {
    if(!isset($vehiclResult[$key]))
        $vehiclResult[$key] = array();      
            $vehiclResult[$key]['SerialEquipment'] = $key. "<br>";    
            $vehiclResult[$key]['Code'] = $obj->Code. "<br>";
            $vehiclResult[$key]['Desc Short'] = $obj->Desc_Short. "<br>";
            $vehiclResult[$key]['Desc Long'] = $obj->Desc_Long. "<br>";  

    foreach($obj->Esaco as $key2 => $obj2) {  
        if($obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode === null){
            // doesn't contain Esaco
            continue;
        }
        else{
           if(!isset($vehiclResult[$key][$key2]))
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2] = array();
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['esaco'] = $key2. "<br>";
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoMainGroupCode'] = $obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode. "<br>";
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoMainGroupDesc'] = $obj2->EsacoMainGroupDesc. "<br>";
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoSubGroupCode'] =  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupCode. "<br>";
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoSubGroupDesc'] =  utf8_decode($obj2->EsacoSubGroupDesc). "<br>";
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoGroupCode'] =     $obj2->EsacoGroupCode. "<br>";
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoGroupDesc'] =     utf8_decode($obj2->EsacoGroupDesc). "<br>";
        }       
    }           
 }       


 $result = array(       
   'vehicle' => $vehiclResult
 );   
 echo json_encode($result);
 die(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your array have the key so:

```
if(!isset($vehiclResult[$key]))
```

if not, you need to create it:

```
$vehiclResult[$key] = array(); // as an array
```

Also, you don't really need to make a description of your "item". You can Parse your JSON on the result page to output some text.

You can do something like.

Do something like:

```
foreach($Serial as $key => $obj) {
    if(!isset($vehiclResult[$key]))
        $vehiclResult[$key] = array();

    $vehiclResult[$key]['serial'] = $key;
    $vehiclResult[$key]['code'] = $obj->Code;
    $vehiclResult[$key]['short_desc'] = $obj->Desc_Short;
    $vehiclResult[$key]['long_desc'] = $obj->Desc_Long;

    foreach($obj->Esaco as $key2 => $obj2) {  
        if($obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode === null){
            // doesn't contain Esaco
            continue;
        }
        else{
           if(!isset($vehiclResult[$key][$key2]))
             $vehiclResult[$key][$key2] = array();
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['esaco'] = $key2;
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoMainGroupCode'] = $obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode;
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoMainGroupDesc'] = $obj2->EsacoMainGroupDesc;
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoSubGroupCode'] = $obj2->EsacoSubGroupCode;
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoSubGroupDesc'] = utf8_decode($obj2->EsacoSubGroupDesc);
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoGroupCode'] = $obj2->EsacoGroupCode;
           $vehiclResult[$key][$key2]['EsacoGroupDesc'] = utf8_decode($obj2->EsacoGroupDesc);
        }       
    }           
 }       


 $result = array(       
   'vehicle' => $vehiclResult
 );   
 echo json_encode($result);
 die();
```

If you would keep your "text" and your  `<br>` code, do the samething but add what you want to output after the "="

**EDIT**

** A HAVE CHANGE THE CODE PREVIOUSLY..

if you want to test your $vehiclResult, try something like:

```
foreach($vehiclResult as $key=>$value){
   if(!is_array($value))
        var_dump($value);
   else {
       foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
         if(!is_array($value2))
             var_dump($value2);
         else {
               foreach($value2 as $key3=>$value3){
                  var_dump($value3);
               }
         }
   } 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much its running now. But also i am getting few errors with Warning: Illegal string offset for  'serial' and for others also the same ...

Comment: if you foreach() element $vehiclResult and get Value, you need to verify if the element is an array. (because before, you put some "string" in the array. use in your "output foreach", "if(!is_array($value)){ continue; }"

Comment: yes i am trying to output but getting the error with proper results dont knw why?

Comment: this warning usually becuase of not using isset properly i guess ?

Comment: thank you..i have test my code and its running fine with results. I have edited my code as you suggests now only 4 warnings its showing Illegal string offset for 'serial', 'Code','short_desc','long_desc'

Comment: its because you try to get "serial" to an element is not array... so.. add something like is_array() or you array is not the "$key" array...

Comment: ok i tried with is_array its not giving any error now but also not showing the data for serial,code

Comment: Change the output line: in_array.. for the new one

Comment: yes its running fine with results with var_dump but can you please tell me that edit change in code..i tried to use the in_array to new onbe but giving the warning :(

Comment: miss a ) after the line.

Comment: sorry i did not understand and its giving the warning again for serial,code,desc short and long

Comment: check if you have 3 ))) at the end of the in_array line

Comment: no i mean to say the code which you have written before the test code not the test code can you please tell me the changes there ...becuase i checked my results before with that and its running fine ...

Comment: if I undestand your request... your initial code works fine but you get only the last value?

Comment: please check the updated question in which i have change the code as you suggest and its working fine but i have 4 warnings i.e Illegal string offset fopr serial,code,desc short,desc long. When I used in_array it does not give error but also not shows values for this 4 parameters

Comment: can you please tell me i am almost done just want to remove that warning